# How do I keep my internal IP?

Tags: windows-8, ip

Whenever my router restarts (D-Link DIR-655, firmware v2), the internal IPs get scrambled among everyone connected, in the order they connect (and because everyone on the network is set to auto-connect, you never know what you'll get). Is there a way to lock my internal IP so that even on a restart it won't change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is in the router, an option called a static reservation.

What will happen is that when a device connects, it will check the MAC address. If that address is reserved, it assigns the same IP address every time it connects, and doesn't assign that address to any other device. You won't have to change anything on Windows, or your other devices. As well, they will continue to get new addresses on other networks if you move your computer

Comment: Assuming the router supports static reservation, of course. Not all do.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your network card configuration so that it uses a static IP address outside of the range provided by the DHCP server in the router.

Comment: Uhh, how do I do this? Sorry, I'm not good with networking.

Comment: Right click on the applet in the notification area and click `Edit Connections...`. Select the network connection in use and click the `Edit...` button. Go to the `IPv4 Settings` tab, switch the method to `Manual`, click the `Add` button, then fill in the three options in the row it opens up. Add the router as your DNS server, then click `Save...`.

Comment: I don't see where the "Edit connections..." button is. If it helps, I'm on Win8.

Comment: It does help. It helps very, very much. But I don't know how to do it on Windows 8.